# Клик на SubMenuItem в контекстном меню

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

У меня есть дата грид и в ресурсах к ней определено контекстное меню. Оно статичное, но мне нужно динамично добавлять sub MenuItem для одного из айтемов меню (там может быть и один, и два, и три пункта). Для этого я формирую HashSet, который биндится как ItemsSourse в "перент" MenuItem

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="actionsContextMenu">
        <ContextMenu.Items>
            <MenuItem Header="Cut" Click="Cut_Click"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="Delete_Click"></MenuItem>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="promoteMenuItem" Header="Promote" Click="Promote_Click" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PromoteStates}"/>
        </ContextMenu.Items>
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при клике на под айтем меню я не могу определить на какой из доступних пунктов было нажато.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пыталась делать несколько вариантов кастомизации типа `MenuItem state = sender as MenuItem;`, но в большинстве случаев результат таков.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть, что вариант биндинга не такой, но я пыталась биндить как хедер sub MenuItem, тогда отображется только сам обьєкт (HashSet), который биндится.

Comment: Ну вы подписались на событие клика именно по `Promote`, а не по какому-то дочернему пункту

Comment: @АндрейNOP нет, клик на "Promote" не срабатывает, он как раз срабатывает на клик по подпунктам. Но я не знаю как опредилить на какой именно.

Comment: Это потому что событие всплывает :) Попробуйте-ка посмотреть не в `sender`, а в `e.OriginalSource`

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, есть) Спасибо!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы подписались на событие клика по пункту `promoteMenuItem`, а не по его дочернему подпункту, поэтому в `sender` именно `promoteMenuItem` (да, событие всплывает), настоящий источник события ищите в `e.OriginalSource`:

```
MenuItem state = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
```

Другой вариант — подписаться именно на клик по дочернему элементу:

```
<MenuItem Header="Promote" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PromoteStates}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_Click"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

В этом случае, в `sender` будет именно тот дочерний пункт, по которому был щелчок.